# Maven artifact benchmarking

Tags: maven, statistics, benchmarking, maven-shade-plugin, maven-central

My shaded artifact is currently 1060 KB.

Are there any websites (Google is yet to provide assistance in this regard) that provide statistical information about the size of artifacts in Maven Central?

I am wanting to benchmark the size of my maven artifact.  Is it big, normal or small by Maven Central standard?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the background by that?

Comment: What do you mean? I want to know if my artifact is too big my Maven Central standards

Comment: There is not standard about size of artifacts and it does not make sense. In Central there are jar,war,zip's etc. which different in size dramtically. Take a look here: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|com.jcabi|mysql-dist|5.6.21|zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is of not that size that you should be worrying about, for example: see [this artifact's](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-math3/3.1.1) size 18M,

You can browse around randomly or you can script it out on your local maven cache to determine average, max and min size, I don't know of any site which does this, at least I don't see a real usecase of it